# Getting rows that share the same - latest - timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

Having:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [MyDevice](
    [DeviceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL
) 


DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [MyTelemetry]
CREATE TABLE [MyTelemetry](
    [DeviceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TelemetryAtUtc] [datetime2](3) NOT NULL,
    [V] [numeric](8, 3) NULL,
) 

INSERT INTO [MyDevice] ([DeviceId], [Name]) VALUES 
    (0, 'Device 0'),
    (1, 'Device 1'),
    (2, 'Device 2'),
    (3, 'Device 3'),
    (4, 'Device 4'),
    (5, 'Device 5')

INSERT INTO [MyTelemetry] ([DeviceId], [TelemetryAtUtc], [V]) VALUES 
    (0, '2023-06-19 05:11:00', 0.11),
    (0, '2023-06-19 05:12:00', 0.12),
    (0, '2023-06-19 05:13:00', 0.13), 

    (1, '2023-06-19 05:11:00', 1.11),
    (1, '2023-06-19 05:12:00', 1.12),
    (1, '2023-06-19 05:12:30', 1.123), -- It's not common but there cane be multiple telemetry records per device per minute
    (1, '2023-06-19 05:13:00', 1.13),

    (2, '2023-06-19 05:11:00', 2.11),
    (2, '2023-06-19 05:12:00', 2.12),
    (2, '2023-06-19 05:13:00', 2.13),

    (3, '2023-06-19 05:11:00', 3.11),
    (3, '2023-06-19 05:12:00', 3.12),  -- Device 3 doesn't have data for minute 05:13:00
    -- Extra test data

    (4, '2023-06-19 05:10:00', 4.10),

    (5, '2023-06-19 05:15:00', 5.15)


    -- The table has 1440 (number of minutes in 24h) * tens_of_thousands records
```

I need to retrieve data for devices meeting some criteria, but for a minute where there is  telemetry for all of them.

Segmented by a minute the data looks like this:

| TheMinute | d0 | d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 | d5 | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-06-19 00:10:00 |  |  |  |  | * |  | Only d4 has data for this minute |
| 2023-06-19 00:11:00 | * | * | * | * |  |  | d0-d3 have data |
| 2023-06-19 00:12:00 | * | ** | * | * |  |  | d0-d3 have data; d1 has 2 data points |
| 2023-06-19 00:13:00 | * | * | * |  |  |  |  |
| 2023-06-19 00:14:00 |  |  |  |  |  | * |  |

#### Case 1. D1,D2,D3

When asking for devices (1,2,3) the desired rows are from minute 2023-06-19 5:12
because the more recent minute that has telemetry for d1, d2 and d3 is 5:12, d1 has two rows for this minute and the more recent one is returned:

```
Id  Name        TelemetryAtUtc              V   
1   Device 1    2023-06-19 05:12:30.000     1.123   
2   Device 2    2023-06-19 05:12:00.000     2.12    
3   Device 3    2023-06-19 05:12:00.000     3.12
```

#### Case 2. D1,D2,D3,D4,D5

There is no minute that has data for all 5 devices, which means I won't be using the telemetry data in my code.

I still need to return row for all devices (for other - non-telemetry - data about them) and I don't mind if `TelemetryAtUtc` and `V` have values or are nulls.

In the code which consumes the result of the SQL I check `TelemetryAtUtc` and I don't use the `V` if `TelemetryAtUtc` is not the same for all records.

For example, this would be fine result:

```
Id  Name        TelemetryAtUtc              V   
5   Device 5    2023-06-19 05:15:00.000     5.15    
1   Device 1    2023-06-19 05:12:30.000     1.123   
2   Device 2    2023-06-19 05:12:00.000     2.12    
3   Device 3    2023-06-19 05:12:00.000     3.12    
4   Device 4    2023-06-19 05:10:00.000     4.1
```

Similarly, in case of ties - e.g. when 3 devices have telemetry at 5:11 and 3 devices have telemetry at 5:12 - I also don't mind the result as long as I can tell that there is no minute with telemetries for all devices.

*The Question*

Is there a performant way to achieve this?

---

I came up with the following (fiddle is http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/51c85/1):

```sql
declare @FromUtc DATETIME2 = '2023-06-19 05:09:00' -- in real life it's DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETUTCDATE());

-- 1. Find the last telemetries for each minute in the last 15 minutes
; WITH DesiredDevices AS (
    SELECT 
        DeviceId, Name 
    FROM MyDevice 
    WHERE DeviceId IN (1,2,3,4,5) -- more complex in real life 
    )
, per_minute AS (
    SELECT 
        row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY t.DeviceId, DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, TelemetryAtUtc ) ORDER BY TelemetryAtUtc DESC) AS minute_row_number,
        (DATEDIFF(MINUTE, 0, TelemetryAtUtc)) AS TelemetryAtUtcMinute,
        t.DeviceId,
        TelemetryAtUtc,
        V
    FROM MyTelemetry t
    join DesiredDevices d ON d.DeviceId = t.DeviceId
    WHERE TelemetryAtUtc > @FromUtc
    )
, one_per_minute AS (SELECT * FROM per_minute T WHERE minute_row_number = 1)
, minute_count AS (    
    SELECT 
        TelemetryAtUtcMinute,
        Count(*) AS NoOfTelems
    FROM one_per_minute d 
    GROUP BY TelemetryAtUtcMinute
    )
, X AS
(
    SELECT 
        d.DeviceId, 
        d.Name, 
        t.TelemetryAtUtc, 
        t.V,
        t.TelemetryAtUtcMinute,
        mc.NoOfTelems
        , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY d.DeviceId ORDER BY NoOfTelems desc, t.TelemetryAtUtcMinute DESC) AS rnx
    FROM DesiredDevices d 
    LEFT JOIN one_per_minute t ON  d.DeviceId = t.DeviceId
    LEFT JOIN minute_count mc ON mc.TelemetryAtUtcMinute = t.TelemetryAtUtcMinute
)
SELECT * 
FROM X
WHERE rnx = 1
ORDER by TelemetryAtUtcMinute DESC
```

which results in an acceptable result:

```
DeviceId    Name    TelemetryAtUtc  V   TelemetryAtUtcMinute    NoOfTelems  rnx
5   Device 5    2023-06-19 05:15:00.000     5.15    64935675    1   1
1   Device 1    2023-06-19 05:12:30.000     1.123   64935672    3   1
2   Device 2    2023-06-19 05:12:00.000     2.12    64935672    3   1
3   Device 3    2023-06-19 05:12:00.000     3.12    64935672    3   1
4   Device 4    2023-06-19 05:10:00.000     4.1     64935670    1   1
```

Comment: I don't understand the logic. Do you or do you not need all the rows to be in the same minute? If yes, why is that result acceptable? If not then by what logic do you want to select a particular minute? And what do you want if there are multiple minutes which fit the criteri?

Comment: I need all *devices* and if all devices have records for a minute I need the most recent minute like this. If there is no minute with telemetry for all devices the  I still need all devices but what's in the telemetry doesnt matter as I wont use it in this case.

Comment: So isn't just: the most recent row for each `DeviceId`? What does "there is no minute with telemetry for all devices" mean here, there will always be at least one row *somewhere* for each device?

Comment: @Charlieface I added ascii art, I hope this helps. For the aggregation I need to perform the data has to be from the same minute bucket ("the same minute") and I cannot just take the latest data. For the minute at 5:13 devices D4 and D5 don't have telemetry so I cannot perform the aggregation.

Comment: No sorry that pictogram really isn't helping. Can you describe all the steps to get your desired results? What result do you want for D4 and D5 and why? It seems they do have telemetry just not in the same minute as the others, so what is the logic exactly behind your results?

Comment: I updated the question, I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do what you did inline:

```sql
SELECT  TOP 1 WITH TIES * -- 4.
    FROM    (
        SELECT  count(*) OVER(partition BY cast(telemetryAtutc AS date), datepart(hour, telemetryatutc), datepart(minute, telemetryatutc)) AS cnt -- 3. count per minute
        ,   *
        FROM    (
                SELECT  deviceid, max(telemetryatutc) AS telemetryatutc -- 2. collapse multiple times per device
                FROM    MyTelemetry
                WHERE   DeviceId IN (1,2,3,4,5) -- 1. add selections here
                GROUP BY deviceid, cast(telemetryAtutc AS date), datepart(hour, telemetryatutc), datepart(minute, telemetryatutc)
                ) x
        ) x
    ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition BY deviceid ORDER BY cnt DESC, telemetryatutc DESC) -- 4.
```

1. Here you add your selections on devices dates
2. This part makes sure there's only one device per minute, so they don't skewer the calculation of devices per minute later
3. This creates a per minute counter
4. The order by gets first row based on the counter first and the last telemetry date second. This ensures we prioritize the minutes with most calculations. WITH TIES is a trick which fetches first row only per deviceId

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER WITH TIES` is inefficient as it requires an extra sort.